# JNI Exception: jarray is an invalid global reference

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

Getting the following exception from JNI via CheckJNI.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray is an invalid global reference: 0x8f635e1e (0xdead4321)
```

Happens during:

```
uint32_t* ConvertIntArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jintArray intArray)
{
   return (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, intArray, NULL);
}
```

which is called from:

```
uint32_t* indexes = ConvertIntArray(env, cls, planeLengths);
```

which is in:

```
jlong Java_<censored>(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jlong state, jintArray planeLengths)
```

Everything happens within the above function so no global references are made. planeLengths is passed directly into ConvertIntArray which should return the uint32 pointer of it. Google has no results on the JNI error either.

Note: The above lines are after all the C preprocessing is done. There are several macros that substitute in different code which is why the ConvertIntArray function seems pointless.

My colleage and myself are stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where does `planeIndexes` come from? Your JNI function receives a `jintArray`, but that one is called `planeLengths`.

Comment: My bad. I truncated most of the arguments but left the wrong one behind.

Comment: I would say you have a memory corruption somewhere else.

Comment: While it could be possible, after returning from ConvertIntArray, the logic is all done on native C data types which are the same when the above is called in C#.

Comment: Are you calling ReleaseIntArrayElements somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out it was a memory corruption. In the question, I truncated several of the long parameters to make the question shorter. As it turned out, Java was passing in ints instead of longs which being smaller variables, shifted some of the pointers back. So, it basically corrupted the jobjects.